# Either or nor condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a question in SQL Server

Table : emp

```
  Id  | Action  | deptno
  ----+---------+-------
  1   | D       |10
  2   | D       |
  3   | C       |20
  4   | A       |
  5   | D       |
```

Here based on condition  if action = D  or deptno is empty or null then we need to retrieve that record

Based on above table I want output like this:

```
Id  |  Action   | Deptno
----+-----------+-------
 1   |  D        |10
 2   |  D        |
 4   |  A        |
 5   |  D        |
```

and another condition is  action!='D' and Deptno !=''
I want like another output like below

```
Id  |  Action   | Deptno
    ----+-----------+-------
3   | C       |20
```

I tried this query:

```
select * 
from emp 
where action = 'D' and deptno=''
```

but this does not return the expected result.

Please tell me how to write the query to get the expected results from SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from emp where Action ='D' OR Deptno='' OR Deptno is null
```

Comment: Well, this does provide an answer, before he edited his question.@Wtower